# 100% height on mobile browser using CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm working on my website and I want it to look really simple on mobile, basically there are just three sections, each one should fit window width and height

```
<section style="width: 100%; min-height: 100%">
   
</section>
```

It looks perfect on my computer browser in device mode, but when I open it on my mobile (iPhone), there is a problem with url bar, which gets smaller, as we slide down. On page load, min-height adapts to browser height including the bar, and it doesn't change when bar changes it's dimension. So it doesn't fit the screen anymore. I tried this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height">
```

But then, sections are to high, obviously. Probably I could do some workaround in jQuery, but I'd rather not. I hope there is some simple solutions in CSS.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: On Safari mobile I believe the body has to be positioned relative to use height: 100%;, not sure though

Comment: You could try viewport units - `100vh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dynamic viewport units should help: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#viewport-variants

For example, setting `height` to `100dvh` would make the height equal to 100% of the dynamic viewport height. The dynamic height is affected by any interfaces that are dynamically expanded and retracted, such as the URL bar on a mobile phone browser.

Additionally, at least Chrome on Android requires `interactive-widget` property in the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) meta tag. For example: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resizes-content">`

Comment: This is a great answer, why no upvote?

Comment: I suggest to add a visible code block to this answer:
min-height: 100dvh

Answer (score 18):

This is not as easy as one may think.

Here are some extract from [The trick to viewport units on mobile](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/):

> Case in point: should the scrollbar be taken into account for the vw unit? What about a site's navigation or page controls — should those count in the calculation? Then there are physical attributes of the devices themselves (hello, notch!) that can't be overlooked.

And then the solution propose:

```css
.my-element {
  height: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}
```

And some JS:

```js
// First we get the viewport height and we multiple it by 1% to get a value for a vh unit
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
// Then we set the value in the --vh custom property to the root of the document
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
```

And some more JS:

```js
// We listen to the resize event
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // We execute the same script as before
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});
```

Answer (score 12):

You could try the `vh` (viewport height) unit in your min-height style.

```
<section style="width: 100%; min-height: 100vh">

</section>
```

Another option would be to use `calc()`.

```
<section style="width: 100%; height: calc(100%);">

</section>
```

Comment: Actually it does on safari, but doesn't work on chrome. :( 
Thank's anyway, it's best solution so far,  I've never used this unit before.

Comment: Thank you, the second option worked. Never thought I'd try that one!

Comment: calc(100%) works better on mobile bc it does not create v-scroll, different from min-height: 100vh, since mobile browsers adds a floating nav bar

Answer (score 2):

You may try this the **scale** meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: I'm using it as well, I think it's required for every responsive page to work properly on mobile. But it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: So...does it help or not in your case ?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo! It doesn't. :(